How to analyze the click on a share link?
In my Swiftui app I'm using a share link like this
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
 
    var body: some View {
        ShareLink(item: URL(string: "SOME_URL")!) {
            Image(systemName: "square.and.arrow.up.circle.fill")
        }
        // how to implement?
        //Analytics.logEvent(...)
    }
}

#Preview {
    ContentView()
}

and would like to use Firebase to get the information whether that link is being clicked by calling Analytics.logEvent(...)
But how do I have to implement the Analytics.logEvent() so it gets fired if the share link is being used?
I tried the onTapGesture
.onTapGesture{
     Analytics.logEvent(...)
}

but then the sharelink doesn't work on click any more
Thank you in advance

So what you want here is to add your own TapGesture logic, without overriding ShareLink's own (embedded) gesture logic.
This is what .simultaneousGesture is for:
        ShareLink(item: URL(string: "SOME_URL")!) {
            Image(systemName: "square.and.arrow.up.circle.fill")
        }
        .simultaneousGesture( // <-- allows view-defined gestures to also trigger
            TapGesture()
                .onEnded {
                    //Analytics.logEvent(...)
                }
        )

(I actually learned this thanks to your question)

Awesome @27shutterclicks :-) it works. Thanks man.

You'll get there soon! As to the simultaneous gesture, I think Apple should more aptly rename it: extension View {  func piggyBackGesture<T>(_ gesture: T, including mask: GestureMask = .all) -> some View where T : Gesture {   self    .simultaneousGesture(gesture)  } } :) This is just for my own fun.
